# Making Unique ID field for Ordinary Least Squares in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics

I need to perform an OLS (Ordinary Least Squares) but ArcGIS asks for a unique ID field. I have a field which would be the right candidate, it's a FIPS number (12 chars), which I have made a number, and text in Excel to no avail. OLS does not work without it...

How can I make it a legal Unique ID field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005p00000022000000) states that the column must be an integer (by which it means 32-bit integer).  If the table doesn't have a rowid column, adding a field, calculating it to row number, and altering it to be NOT NULL should do the trick
(though that last part may not be necessary).

Comment: THat's a Long Integer? Precision 32? How do you calculate a row number?

Comment: http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38517

Comment: In addition, you could add a field and make it equal to a pre-credefined field that already has the right numbering

Comment: No, you can't use a 12-digit value as a registered rowid, because it could/would overflow a 32-bit integer field.